# ListView selecting single item , wpf

Tags: wpf, listview

i have a listview and it's items source is a list . I want a user to pick only one item . When I set SelectionMode of the listview to single , the user can still select several items and it seems like the listview is going crazy and selects items that user didn't select... looks very strange... can anyone know what could be the problem?

I cann't paste here a screenshot , i don't have the paste option.....

this is a xaml -

```
<StackPanel MinWidth="600" Margin="0,0,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="600">
    <GroupBox Header="Command Queue" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="CornflowerBlue">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1.5" CornerRadius="10">
                            <ListView SelectionMode="Single" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Margin="5" Name="ListView_CmdQ" ItemsSource="{Binding}" MaxHeight="450" FontFamily="verdana" FontSize="12">
                            </ListView>
                        </Border>
                    </GroupBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: The xaml code would also be nice to see.

Comment: Do you change any Property or behaviour of your ListView from the code behind? I cannot see anything wrong with the list view as it is in the xaml.

Comment: the only thing i do in the code behind is       this.ListView_CmdQ.DataContext = list_listItems;

Comment: Okay I pasted your xaml code and added the following code to the Code-behind file: List<string> items = new List<string>();

            items.Add("BLA");
            items.Add("BL2");
            items.Add("BL3");
            items.Add("BL4");
            items.Add("BL5");

            ListView_CmdQ.DataContext = items;

This produces a perfectly working ListView where only single selection is possible.

Comment: What exactly contains list_listItems?

Comment: it contains a strings.... i will try to make a new list and bind it to the listview...

Comment: I made a new list and it is still picks several items... ans also when i click the first item , it picks the first one and the third one.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the items in your list appear more than once?  I've seen this problem before where you have something like this:

```
var a = new Thing();
var b = new Thing();

var myList = new List<Thing>();
myList.Add(a);
myList.Add(b);
myList.Add(a);
myList.Add(b);
```

If you were to bind a `ListView` to the `myList`, you'd get the behaviour you've described.  I think basically it's to do with the fact that multiple items in the list match the `SelectedItem`, so the styling of the list gets a bit confused.  One way around it is to wrap each item in another class:

```
var myList = new List<WrappedThing>();
myList.Add(new WrappedThing((a));
myList.Add(new WrappedThing((b));
myList.Add(new WrappedThing((a));
myList.Add(new WrappedThing((b));
```

... which means that each item in the list is unique, even though the item they're wrapping may not be.

Comment: @olia Please click the checkmark on the left to mark Dan Puzey's answer as correct if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your list_listItems contains the same string twice, you get this behavior. This happens with value types and reference strings. You should probably wrap each string in a TextBlock and put that in the listview.

It looks like this is reported as a bug still active (since 2007) [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/274831/listbox-display-issue-when-duplicate-items-selected).

Comment: a.....o.k. now i see my problem , i put in the list a lot of the same strings.... thanks.