# How to get indices of selected items in WPF's listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, indexing, selection

Before you mark this question as a duplicate or suggest using Items.IndexOf, please do the following:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var A = new object();
    var B = new object();
    var C = new object();

    lbItems.Items.Add(A);
    lbItems.Items.Add(B);
    lbItems.Items.Add(C);
    lbItems.Items.Add(A);
    lbItems.Items.Add(B);
    lbItems.Items.Add(C);
}

private void lbItems_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(lbItems.Items.IndexOf(lbItems.SelectedItems[0]).ToString());
}
```

Then doubleclick fourth element (you'll get 0 instead of 3).

How to get a list of selected item indices?

Comment: After much confusion, (which I'm sure your sharing). I think whats happening is its getting the first index of object `A` which is 0. You could create a loop to get all indexes of `A`

Comment: @Sayse: you are correct - the `ListBox` will pick up the first index (also, if you click on the fourth element, both the first and fourth elements will often be highlighted).  I posted a solution for that on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469700/listview-selecting-single-item-wpf/5470094#5470094).

Comment: @DanPuzey - Your solution would probably be the answer to this question also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by you adding the same object to the list twice.  The `ListBox` control can't tell between them.  One way around this problem is to wrap each item in another class:

```
lbItems.Items.Add(new WrappedThing((a));
lbItems.Items.Add(new WrappedThing((b));
lbItems.Items.Add(new WrappedThing((a));
lbItems.Items.Add(new WrappedThing((b));
```

... which means that each item in the list is unique, even though the item they're wrapping may not be.  Note that any data template or bindings would also have to change to support this, though you could do this with a single global `DataTemplate`.

`WrappedThing` would look something like this:

```
class WrappedThing<T>
{
    public WrappedThing(T thing)
    {
        Thing = thing;
    }

    public T Thing { get; private set; }
}
```

(Note: this is copied from my answer to a different question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469700/listview-selecting-single-item-wpf/5470094#5470094) since the answer is useful but the question is slightly different.)

Answer (score 3):

Further to my comment (" its getting the first index of object A which is 0"),

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < lbItems.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (lbItems.Items[i] == lbItems.SelectedItems[0])
      j++;
}
MessageBox.Show(lbItems.Items.IndexOf(lbItems.SelectedItems[0]).ToString()
+ string.Format("\r\nThere are {0} occurences of this object in this list", j));
```

Comment: Note: I do not intend this as an answer to the question asked, but further clarification